# Will the username and password be sent over the internet in plain text?

Tags: android, x509certificate, httpsurlconnection, sslsocketfactory, x509trustmanager

I am using this snippet to authenticate with a https & htpasswd protected server:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(object : Authenticator() {
    override fun getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication {
        return PasswordAuthentication("usernameinplaintext", "passwordinplaintext".toCharArray())
    }
})

var sentBytes: Long = 0
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(NullHostNameVerifier())
val context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
context.init(null, arrayOf<X509TrustManager>(NullX509TrustManager()), SecureRandom())
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.socketFactory)
```

Will the username and password be sent over the internet in plain text?

Comment: Log the values on the server, if possible, and find out

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: According to the code, the transport between endpoints is protected with TLS, so they will be encrypted during transmission.